# Windows Phone Emulator Won't Start, NetBT error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Windows Phone Emulator can not start. When I try to start emulator say "Windows Phone Os is Starting". I looked the Computer Management/Event Viewer. When I try to start Windows phone Emulator, in the system log some errors appear.

**1st**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        NetBT
Date:          12/8/2013 23:08:11
Event ID:      4307
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      birfincankafein
Description:   Initialization failed because the transport refused to open initial addresses.
```

**2nd:**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch
Date:          12/8/2013 23:08:04
Event ID:      27
Task Category: (1019)
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      birfincankafein
Description:
Networking driver in Emulator 8.0.10322 WXGA.metehan loaded but has a different version from the server. Server version 5.0  Client version 4.0 (Virtual machine ID B0F3F3F5-7D6F-4551-848D-230DF063B1DF). The device will work, but this is an unsupported configuration. This means that technical support will not be provided until this problem is resolved. To fix this problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from the Action menu.
```

**3th:**

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        storvsp
Date:          12/8/2013 23:08:01
Event ID:      6
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      birfincankafein
Description:
A storage device in 'Emulator 8.0.10322 WXGA.metehan' loaded but has a different version from the server.  Server version 6.0  Client version 5.1 (Virtual machine ID B0F3F3F5-7D6F-4551-848D-230DF063B1DF). The device will work, but this is an unsupported configuration. This means that technical support will not be provided until this problem is resolved. To fix this problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from the Action menu.
```

Comment: Do you have Windows 8 Pro installed?

Comment: This sounds like a version mismatch between the Windows Phone SDK your running the the host OS you're running it on.

Comment: Dumb question, but have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the SDK. I Had this problem before, and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Try it. I uninstall everything abaout visual studio. SDKs Blend 2012 - 2013 Visual Studio 2012 - 2013. But not fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what it suggests in the error message?

> To fix this problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from the Action menu.

[edit]
I jumped ahead and tried this, but I don't think it will ultimately help you.  I could insert the virtual Integration Services Setup Disk, but could not get it to run.  See below...

Instead, I think you'll have to look wider to resolve this problem.  First off, make sure you're running a host OS that supports Hyper-V, the virtual machine management component.  This is the *professional* edition of Win7 (for VS2012) or Win8 (VS2013).  If you do have a capable host OS, then try re-installing the existing instance of Visual Studio (Control, Programs and Features, right click on VS...). And if that doesn't work, *remove* Visual Studio, reboot, reinstall.  And if that doesn't work, I know not what.

Here's what I tried with Integration Services.  Maybe a wiser head can jump in and provide the missing magic...

1. on a Pro edition of Windows...
2. Install Hyper-V Manager, if you don't already have it. (Control
   Panel, Programs and Features, Turn Windows Features On or Off,
   select 'Hyper-V' then check both platform and management tools.). 
   Reboot.
3. Open Hyper-V manager(Home screen, start typing 'hyper', Search will
   find it.)
4. Under 'Virtual Machines', highlight one of the Emulator ... virtual
   machines.  Right click, 'Connect'.
5. Verify emulator is currently powered off (i.e, not showing WP home
   screen in emulator).
6. In 'Emulator ...' window, 'File' menu, choose 'Settings'.
7. In 'Settings for Emulator ...' window, highlight IDE controller 1'
   in left hand panel.
8. In right hand panel, highlight 'DVD drive' and click Add.
9. Now start up the emulator VM.  Back in 'Emulator ...' window,
   'Action' menu, select 'Power on'.  In the main panel, you should
   shortly see the WP home screen.
10. Finally, 'Action' menu, 'Insert Integration Services Setup Disk'. 
     Hyper-V knows where it is.

And... nothing happens.  I see no indication that the VM ran the setup program or did anything.  Maybe, if your VM was somehow misconfigured in the first place, this will silently fix your problem.  Friendly wizards invited to incant.

Comment: How can you connect to the Virtual machine and use a setup disk? The "Virtual machine" is the Windows Phone OS.

Comment: Try it. But my problem continues.